# My program in 8086/8088 assembly prints extra characters

Tags: assembly, printing, x86-16

A wrote a program in emu8086 that reads 2 32-bit hex numbers and calculates their product which is a 64-bit number. Because the registers are 16-bit I read 4 digits every time and store them in one of them. My problem is that when i read and print (for the user to see what he typed) the digits, every 4 digits my program prints an extra character. I cannot find any mistakes so i put here the routines that i assume must cause this.

```
READ_HEX PROC NEAR
LL: READ
    CMP AL,'0'
    JL LL
    CMP AL,'9'
    JLE NEXT1
    CMP AL,'A'
    JL LL
    CMP AL,'F'
    JLE NEXT2
NEXT1:      
    PRINT AL
    SUB AL,30H
    RET
NEXT2:      
    PRINT AL
    SUB AL,37H  
    RET    
READ_HEX ENDP

MAKE_16_BIT PROC NEAR
    MOV CX,4
    MOV BX,0 
    MOV AX,0
L:  CALL READ_HEX
    MOV AH,0
    ROL BX,4
    ADD BX,AX
    LOOP L    
MAKE_16_BIT ENDP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very restricted amount of code you've given us, and completely free of context, I'd suggest you may be missing a `ret` from the second procedure.

Comment: sorry for giving such a small part but the program is chaotic and i knew the problem was here. believe it or not i hadn't seen there was no ret! thnx a lot!